# Error running react-native start on project after expo eject

Tags: react-native, expo

I just ejected my project from Expo using expo eject, and when I try to run it using react-native start, I get the following error message in my Terminal:

```
events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:127:28)
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at NodeWatcher.checkedEmitError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:143:12)
    at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:133:12) {
  errno: -24,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  filename: null
}
```

I can't make out what I need to know to resolve this issue, so can someone point out the proper steps I should take to get my project running on react-native? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Run the following in your command line to install watchman:

```
brew update
brew install watchman
```

Comment: It's a good first thing to try, but it doesn't always fix the problem (didn't work for me).

Comment: Running `brew reinstall watchman` finally fixed the error for me (had to do `xcode-select --install` for it to work too).

Answer (score 0):

try installing watchman - this improves on file watching capabilities of the react native packager server. see: https://facebook.github.io/watchman/